# FFmpeg keep framerate of input video despite overlay on color source

Tags: ffmpeg, video

- FFmpeg can `overlay` ([docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)) videos like this:

`ffmpeg -i inputA_60fps.mp4 -i inputB_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v] [1:v] overlay=shortest=1" output1.mp4`

-> The frame rate of `output1.mp4` is automatically the same as that of the inputs (60). I like this.

- FFmpeg can also overlay on a `color` ([docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-colorchart_002c-colorspectrum_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc)) source like this:

`ffmpeg -i input_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "color=c=black [c]; [c] [0:v] overlay=shortest=1" output2.mp4`

-> The frame rate of `output2.mp4` is always 25, because the default frame rate of the `color` source is 25, even though the input has a frame rate of 60. I don't like this.

- The `color` frame rate can be specified explicitly like this:

`ffmpeg -i input_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "color=c=black:r=30 [c]; [c] [0:v] overlay=shortest=1" output3.mp4`

-> But then the frame rate of `output3.mp4` is always that fixed value 30. I don't like this.

Question: How can the output frame rate instead automatically use the same frame rate as the input again?

(Setting `:duration=0.001` or `-vsync passtrough` didn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

I found no  way to use `color` with `overlay` and keep the framerate of the input video.

But [xstack](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos%20using%20xstack) can sometimes be used instead of `overlay`, and `xstack` has `fill`, which does not have the same problem as `color`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `color` source, you can make a copy of the original source and paint every frame black and then use this as your overlay background. It will have the same dimensions and framerate as the original.

```
ffmpeg -i input_60fps.mp4 -filter_complex "drawbox=t=fill:c=black [c]; [c][0:v] overlay [c]; [c] [0:v] overlay=shortest=1" output3.mp4
```